# ASP.NET MVC4: How to convert an IEnumerable to a string for ViewBag

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work:

```
HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
IEnumerable<Hardware> Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));
ViewBag.Pcs = Pcs.ToString();
```

So how do I convert my IEnumerable to a string (or other primitive data type) so the compiler won't give me an error when I try to use it in my Razor?

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Pcs) {
     <li><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-hdd"></i> @item.HType</a></li>
}
```

Hardware class:

```
public class Hardware
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DeviceType> Type { get; set; }
        public string AssetTagId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Manufacturer> Manufacturer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ServiceTagId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(75)]
        public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
       // [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string WarrantyExpiration { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string WarrantyType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Location { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HardwareType> HardwareType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(2000)]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string POATag { get; set; }
    }
```

HardwareType class:

```
public class HardwareType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string HType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Hardware> Hardware { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if the problem is that you *are* converting it to a string, here:

```
ViewBag.Pcs = Pcs.ToString();
```

Why are you doing that? It looks like you want to iterate over the individual items within the sequence within your view. Either use:

```
ViewBag.Pcs = Pcs;
```

or

```
ViewBag.Pcs = Pcs.ToList();
```

if you want to force the query to be materialized.

EDIT: Looking at the error again, I suspect it's actually the `Where` clause that's the problem. I suspect you *really* want:

```
var pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Any(hwt => hwt.HType == "PC"));
ViewBag.Pcs = pcs.ToList(); // Materialize the query
```

The problem is trying to use your `hwt` value as *input* to the query...

Comment: I tried ViewBag.Pcs = Pcs and it gave me this error: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'CIT.Models.HardwareType'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`

Comment: Pcs.ToList has the same issue.  Is it the structure of my Hardware class?

Comment: @sehummel: You need to give a *lot* more information about the error. It sounds like that's an error from a query provider, not a compile-time error. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: What do you mean from the query provider?

Comment: @sehummel: See my edit - I suspect the problem is far away from what you think it is.

Comment: @sehummel: I mean the code which is turning your LINQ query into SQL. (You haven't told us anything about which LINQ provider you're using, unfortunately...)

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this.  I'm using Entity Code First.

Comment: A local variable named 'hwt' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'hwt', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.  This is the error your edit gives me.

Comment: Looks like I had a type.  Now it says  HType isn't in my definition of Hardware.

Comment: @sehummel: Well `HType` isn't in `Hardware` - it's in `HardwareType`. What are you really trying to do? You're iterating through a sequence of `Hardware` elements, each of which has multiple `HardwareType` values associated with it... so what do you want your output to be?

Comment: Yes, I know it's not in `Hardware`.  I want to query the database and get all of the PCs.  I probably need some kind of join.  I'm open to whatever you suggest.

Comment: @sehummel: Well you're currently querying all the `Hardware` items. What do you want to do with those? (It sounds like you really need to take a step back and *think* about what you want - you have a design problem at the moment, not a code problem.)